Converting Discount (Amt) to Discount % in Amendment Quote

I have a doubt can anyone please solve it?
In salesforce cpq, QLE, In Amendment Quote, If the product is already having Discount(Amt) in the main Quoteline, In Amendment it should be converted as Discount % that applied to the original Quoteline. So how can I do? Like I know I should create a formula field but in the quote line editor how to display discount amount to discount %?
